# "pdflatex: ! Core one to three" error

Tags: errors, pdftex, compiling

I used a `javascript`program to generate a rather long `.tex` file (8500 lines), but whenever I try to compile it, it gives me an

```
 `pdflatex: ! Core one to three`
```

error.

The error doesn't seem to do anything as there is still an output. There is also no other information and it still occurs if I delete the paragraphs where it is probably located.
I guessed the location within the source from the surrounding **overfull-boxes-warnings**.

Any idea what this error-message is actually meaning?

## EDIT:

So I found the real error-position and where the text comes from:

```
\color{authortext}\rmfamily\normalsize
\\{}\ttfamily "We may as well have with that formation they're taking! Cores one to three are making a triangle, and each one's right around 100 meters off of the center, where the unseen seal is. That's max supercore range as far as we know . I bet that one's got all the good modules and stuff, because he's the only one who can assist the other three." \color{authortext}\rmfamily\normalsize says Scanner.
```

authortext is a color defined with the color-package. `\\{}` I use the `{}`, so in case it is followed by a `[` . `\rmfamily\normalsize` are used so often as I generate this output automatically, so there are paragraphs where this is changed in between.

You might see: "... they're taking **! Cores one to three** are making a triangle, and ..."

That's where the error comes from.

However, what's wrong with this line? ' and " were used previously just fine...
But if I comment this line out, the other 8500 lines are compiled without error...

## EDIT & SOLUTION

Actually this is a bug in TeXnicCenter as it seems.

The log revieled:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3265--3275
 \OT1/cmtt/m/n/10.95 "We may as well have with that for-ma-tion they're tak-ing
! Cores one to three 
 []
```

However, TeXnicCenter counted all the lines with a leading ! as error to display a total error amount at the end of compiling.

In reality, this is actually just a underfull box that contains the line

`"We may as well have with that formation they're taking! Cores one to three`

which was accidentally linebroken at the ! within the log.

Comment: Does this error also occur when you generate much shorter documents?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The error message doesn't seem to come from `pdflatex`.

Comment: @egreg thanks for the welcome! I use miktex and texniccenter and got no other info than the line above. Don't know where it's coming from.

Comment: what happens if you use pdflatex on the commandline ?

Comment: The error message is probably being mangled by your IDE, copy the exact lines from the log file, from the `!` to the `?`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, this seems exactly what is happening. I posted some details in an edit above.

Comment: @Julian So it seems that we should close this question, as it's apparent the issue was caused by a bug in TeXnicCenter  which we can do nothing about. Don't worry and continue to contribute to the site. Welcome again! Maybe you prefer to add a self-answer; if you do, fine, and I'll retract my vote for closing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in TeXnicCenter, as explained in the edits to the question.

Comment: @egreg well, I tried, but as I'm new, I'm not allowed to self-answer before tomorrow^^ though I'm a few years on stackexchange already^^ That's why I put the "answer" into the question as an edit, so people can stop wondering about this question.

Comment: It may be off-topic but I want to upvote for diligence.